# How to avoid DB requery on pagination using ASP Classic and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have a page that querying products from the database and displaying then in pages of 30 items. When I navigate to the next page, the application re-queries the DB and displays page no. 2 and so on.

How can I avoid this database re-query? Can I store the results somewhere? We are talking about 1500-2000 rows/query and when we have 400-450 users online, our dedicated server runs at 100% CPU capacity.

Comment: Use external caching ActiveX or try cache using `Application` object.

Comment: Not necessary anymore. Ran some MySQL optimization commands on the database and processor usage went down to 7-10% immediately. Had no idea those commands really do something.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough memory to pre-load your entire "catalog" (in Application level storage) and then have SQL return all results, but store only the index (in each Session).
Something like this:
    On Application Start: create my read only Application-level cache
    On Search: SQL returns all results (I assume you have to do SQL, so you can check business conditions
    On results: build list of indices that map into Application cache
    On Display Page: Read and display apropriate range from Application cache

If you don't have enough memory, then a "Result" table might provide some optimization: on a per-session basis, cache entire query result into a "flattened" table, to avoid potentially expensive (busines-logic-heavy) products query. You have to be careful to detect when the query changes, so you can discard cache, and also have some server-side logic to cleanup old, expired searches.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated the main reason I was asking for a solution was to avoid CPU overload. It seemed unnatural for the server to be clogged up at 100% with only 500-600 users online. I discovered the optimize table MySQL command, which works on MyISAM tables and it totally solved the problem. Immediately after executing the command, the CPU usage went down to 10-12%.

So, if there is anyone else out there running MySQL applications that overload the CPU, you should first try the Optimize Table command and other maintenance tasks described here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html